# Finding Mod Value

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a problem in finding the solution of the equation given in the form of:$$153^{197}=x \mod 497$$
 Can anyone hep me to solve this question?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand

Comment: As $7\cdot71$

$$153\equiv-1\pmod7\implies153^{197}\equiv(-1)^{197}\equiv-1$$

and 
$$153\equiv11\pmod{71},197\equiv57\pmod{\phi(71)}; 153^{197}\equiv11^{57}\pmod{71}$$